# Fill cells in the column with the index interval in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Part of my dataframes looks like this:

```
         df1                    df2
 scale  col1    col2        col1    col2
   1    item1   NaN         item1     3
   2    item1   NaN         item2     2
   3    item1   NaN         ...
   4    item1   NaN         
   5    item1   NaN         
   6    item1     6         
   7    item1   NaN         
   8    item1   NaN         
   9    item1   NaN         
  10    item1   NaN         
  11    item1   NaN         
  12    item1   NaN         
  13    item1   NaN         
  14    item1   NaN         
  15    item1   NaN         
   1    item2   NaN         
   2    item2   NaN         
   3    item2   NaN         
   4    item2   NaN         
   5    item2   NaN         
   6    item2   NaN         
   7    item2   NaN         
   8    item2     8         
   9    item2   NaN         
  10    item2   NaN         
  11    item2   NaN         
  12    item2   NaN         
  13    item2   NaN         
  14    item2   NaN         
  15    item2   NaN         
  ...
```

I need to do the following for each unique value in column `col1` of `df1` (in the original dataframe there are about 100):

1. Find the first value in `col2` of `df1` that is not empty.
2. And based on the equality of the values in column `col1` of `df2` and column `col1` of `df1`, insert the values from column `col2` of `df2` into column `col2` of `df1`. The values in `col2` of `df2` will also be the interval with which `col2` of `df1` must be filled.

Below is my code, but it adds a value only once:

```
df_test = df1[df1['col2'].notnull()] # find non-empty values
df_test = df_test.set_index(['col1'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['col1'])
df_test['scale'] = df_test['scale'] + df2['col2']
df_test['col2'] = df2['col2']
df_test = df_test.reset_index()
df1 = df1.set_index(['col1', 'scale']).fillna(df_test.set_index(['col1', 'scale'])).reset_index()
```

The result looks like this:

```
 scale  col1    col2
   1    item1   NaN
   2    item1   NaN
   3    item1   NaN
   4    item1   NaN
   5    item1   NaN
   6    item1     6
   7    item1   NaN
   8    item1   NaN
   9    item1     3
  10    item1   NaN
  11    item1   NaN
  12    item1   NaN
  13    item1   NaN
  14    item1   NaN
  15    item1   NaN
   1    item2   NaN
   2    item2   NaN
   3    item2   NaN
   4    item2   NaN
   5    item2   NaN
   6    item2   NaN
   7    item2   NaN
   8    item2     8
   9    item2   NaN
  10    item2     2
  11    item2   NaN
  12    item2   NaN
  13    item2   NaN
  14    item2   NaN
  15    item2   NaN
  ...
```

But he must be so:

```
 scale  col1    col2
   1    item1   NaN
   2    item1   NaN
   3    item1   NaN
   4    item1   NaN
   5    item1   NaN
   6    item1     6
   7    item1   NaN
   8    item1   NaN
   9    item1     3
  10    item1   NaN
  11    item1   NaN
  12    item1     3
  13    item1   NaN
  14    item1   NaN
  15    item1     3
   1    item2   NaN
   2    item2   NaN
   3    item2   NaN
   4    item2   NaN
   5    item2   NaN
   6    item2   NaN
   7    item2   NaN
   8    item2     8
   9    item2   NaN
  10    item2     2 
  11    item2   NaN
  12    item2     2
  13    item2   NaN
  14    item2     2
  15    item2   NaN
...
```

I will be grateful for any recommendations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over groups of items:

The DFs I used:

```
df_item1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['item1']*15,'col2':[np.nan]*15})
df_item1.loc[5,'col2'] = 6
df_item2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['item2']*15,'col2':[np.nan]*15})
df_item2.loc[7,'col2'] = 8
df1 = pd.concat([df_item1,df_item2])
# and
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['item1','item2'],'col2':[3,2]})
```

The code

```
dfs = []
for item, _df in df1.groupby('col1'):

    step = df2[df2.col1==item].col2.values[0]
    start = _df[~np.isnan(_df.col2)].index[0]+step
    stop = _df.index[-1]+1
    index_to_fill = np.arange(start=start,step=step,stop=stop)

    _df.loc[index_to_fill,'col2'] = step
    dfs.append(_df)
df1 = pd.concat(dfs)
```

result :

```
     col1  col2
0   item1   NaN
1   item1   NaN
2   item1   NaN
3   item1   NaN
4   item1   NaN
5   item1   6.0
6   item1   NaN
7   item1   NaN
8   item1   3.0
9   item1   NaN
10  item1   NaN
11  item1   3.0
12  item1   NaN
13  item1   NaN
14  item1   3.0
0   item2   NaN
1   item2   NaN
2   item2   NaN
3   item2   NaN
4   item2   NaN
5   item2   NaN
6   item2   NaN
7   item2   8.0
8   item2   NaN
9   item2   2.0
10  item2   NaN
11  item2   2.0
12  item2   NaN
13  item2   2.0
14  item2   NaN
```

**Explaination** :
I create a collection of DF (`dfs`) that contains the completed `df1` grouped by items.
To complete the groups:

- Find the `step` to apply (`df2.col2` equals item)
- Find the first not nan data of the group (`start`), and the last index (`stop`)
- Generate the "mask" of the rows you need to fill (`index_to_fill`)
- Fill the group with `step` according to the "mask" of index.

Finally concatenate the collection.